# Template literals are not converted correctly by babel-loader and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babel-loader

I want to use babel-loader@8.1.0 to convert this source to es2015 format.

```
var foo = 'test';
console.log(`[this is ${foo}`);
console.log(`[this is ${foo}]`);
```

But I get this result.

```
"use strict";

var foo = 'test';
console.log("[this is " + foo);
console.log(`[this is ${foo}]`);
```

Have you ever seen this phenomenon where brackets at the end do not convert correctly?

I can't show you everything because of my job.

```
//webpack.config.js

moduel.exports = [{
  mode: 'production',
  name: 'js',
  entry: foo.js,
  output: {
    path: foobar,
    filename: bar.js
  },
  moudle: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:/.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets:[['@babel/preset-env', {
              useBuiltIns: 'usage',
              corejs: 2
            }]],
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread'],
            cacheDirectory: true
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried [here](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBAZg9jEF4IHIAuBTAzq5BuAUAMYwB2mMANugHQUwDmAFAAYDaqAFgJaYQ8QASAN6wYAX2YBKAsTKUadJm079-w0WIC6U3EA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Ces2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.11.1&externalPlugins=) and looks okay
```
```

Comment: Can you show the babel preset/config?

Comment: I added preset.

Comment: I Have used you exact webpack preset, but this is the output that I get ```console.log("[this is ".concat("test")), console.log("[this is ".concat("test", "]"))```

Comment: The webpack.config.js has problems or you copy and pasted it wrong. `@babel.preset-env` and `corejs; 2`

Comment: I missed copy, but not working...